# I cannot print out my index numbers without breaking program

Tags: python, indexing

I am trying to get index numbers of an element in a list like this

```
scores = [100,22,33,44,22,56]
```

I want to get the two index number of 22.
I'm trying to do this by storing index numbers into a list.
But after I found two index numbers in this case, the program just abrubtly
ends, because it cannot find any 22 after the 2nd 22 found, thus not giving me chance to print the index numbers I found.
How do you make it print out the index number without any error?

```
scores = [100,22,11,22,44,66,77]
position = 0
counter = []
findthis = 22

for x in scores:
     position = scores.index(findthis, position)
     counter.append(position)
     position = position + 1

print(counter)
```

Comment: What do you mean by "abruptly ends". What error do you get? You should list the traceback, if you get an error.

Comment: 22 is not in list   ----> error message

Comment: That is not a Python traceback; generally, you should really copy-paste the full traceback when asking for help with Python problems.

Answer (score 1):

Use [enumerate](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#enumerate) if you want all the indexes of `findthis` in your scores list:

```
print([i for i, ele in enumerate(scores) if ele == findthis])
```

`i` is the index of each element in scores, `ele` is each actual element.

Once you go past the index of the second `22` in the list, you are getting the error as there is no `22` in the list from there, your code works for two iterations then you are left with `-> 44,66,77]`.

```
scores[position:]
1st iteration -> [22, 11, 22, 44, 66, 77]
2nd           ->  [22, 44, 66, 77]
3rd           ->  [44, 66, 77] # error
```

Answer (score 0):

You should consider this simpler approach:

```
scores = [100,22,11,22,44,66,77]
position = 0
counter = []
findthis = 22

for x in scores:
     if x==findthis:
          counter.append(position)
     position = position + 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's an alternative solution:

```
scores = [100,22,11,22,44,66,77]
counter = []
findthis = 22

for index,value in enumerate(scores):
  if value is findthis:
    counter.append(index)
```

Here's a solution with list comprehension:

```
scores = [100,22,11,22,44,66,77]
findthis = 22

counter=[index for index,value in enumerate(scores) if value is findthis]
```

---

NOTE: I've seen only now that [padraic-cunningham](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2141635/padraic-cunningham) has already given a solution using the **enumerate()** function. Sorry for duplication.